# StackView has stopped getting a height in Xcode 10 / iOS 12

Tags: swift, uiscrollview, ios12

Im creating a `stackView` through my code and adding it to another stackView which is inside a scrollView. After Xcode 10 / ios 12 update my stack view is somehow taking 0 height due to which my scrollView is not able to get a `contentSize`.

My Code is:-

```
fileprivate func createStackViewForRowWithOptionLabel(_ label: TiVoLabel, andControlContainer: UIView) -> UIStackView
{

    let itemStackRow = UIStackView()
    itemStackRow.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    itemStackRow.axis = .horizontal
    itemStackRow.alignment = .fill
    itemStackRow.distribution = .fill
    itemStackRow.spacing = 5
    itemStackRow.setTheme(.default)

    itemStackRow.addArrangedSubview(label)
    itemStackRow.addArrangedSubview(andControlContainer) 

NSLayoutConstraint.activate([itemStackRow.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30)])

    return itemStackRow
}
```

I've tried doing whatever is mentioned in [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52397203/anchor-constraints-not-honored-in-xcode-10-ios-12/52397381#52397381?newreg=ce05a2a86a5949c28f949cd24d3954c7) but its not working

Comment: just remove the height constraint and if your items in stack view is going to be equal height than change the distribution to .fillEqually and give constraint to one of item the rest will be handled by stack view

Comment: Tried what you said . Gave height and width to the label thats inside the itemStackRow. StackView is still not getting a height.

Comment: can you show me stack view constraint

Comment: It has only the height constraint. The code that pasted above is the code for stack view. Constraint for label although is :- NSLayoutConstraint.activate([itemLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 108)])
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([itemLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30)])

Comment: try giving constraint to main stackview

Answer (score 1):

I added a height constraint to the stackView equal to the view in which the scrollView is. Reduced its priority to 750. This seemed to have fixed the issue for me. Haven't been able to figure out the exact reason why in iOS 12 its required to explicitly specify the height.